# I am creating a Object with a scanner, how to I store it into an array to make up a team of user stated parameters

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = null;
        String data1 = null;
        String data2 = null;
        String data3 = null;

        Player a = new Player(data, data1, data2, data3);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter Player Name: ");
        data=scanner.nextLine();
        a.setName(data);
        System.out.println("Please enter Player Position: ");
        data1=scanner.nextLine();
        a.setPosition(data1);
        System.out.println("Please enter Player Age: ");
        data2=scanner.nextLine();
        a.setAge(data2);
        System.out.println("Please enter Player height");
        data3=scanner.nextLine();
        a.setHeight(data3);

        System.out.println(a.toString());

// how do i store this into a array of 6, 
// basically i want to make 6 individual objects and make them be a volleyball team


    }
}
```

Comment: `Player[] players = new Player[6]`? Of course you need a loop for your inputs, so in your case you have to repeat the code above six times (using a loop) in order to create six `Player`.

Comment: Declare an array of type `Player` and use a loop to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

First don't create an object with `null` values then populate with real values, just do it in one shot. Then use a loop and an array to create many of them :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Player[] players = new Player[6];

for(int i=0 ; i<players.length ; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter Player Name: ");
    String  data = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Player Position: ");
    String  data1 = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Player Age: ");
    String  data2 = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter Player height");
    String  data3 = scanner.nextLine();

    Player a = new Player(data, data1, data2, data3);
    players[i] = a;

    System.out.println(a.toString());
}
```